# jQuery .match() strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I wish in javascript when pasting the url of a youtube or facebook video, to get the id of this video.
This is very strange because it works correctly only if the ID does not exceed a certain number of characters.

Here is the markup

```
<input type="text" name="jform[id_facebook]" id="jform_id_facebook" value="" class="js-facebook-vid" 
size="20" placeholder="Entrer URL Facebook" maxlength="50" aria-invalid="false">

<input type="text" name="jform[id_youtube]" id="jform_id_youtube" value="" class="js-youtube-vid" 
size="20" placeholder="Entrer URL YouTube" maxlength="50" aria-invalid="false">
```

and the jquery code

```
jQuery('#jform_id_facebook').on('paste', function () {
  var newval1 = '';  
  $this = jQuery(this);
  setTimeout(function(){ 
      if (newval1 = $this.val().match(/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\..*v=(\d+)/)) {
          $this.val(newval1[1]);
      } else if (newval1 = $this.val().match(/(\/videos\/)([^\/]+)/)) {
        $this.val(newval1[1]);
      } 
  }, 800);
});

jQuery('#jform_id_youtube').on('paste', function () {
  var newval2 = '';
  $this = jQuery(this);
  setTimeout(function(){ 
      if (newval2 = $this.val().match(/(\?|&)v=([^&#]+)/)) {
          $this.val(newval2.pop());
      } else if (newval2 = $this.val().match(/(\.be\/)+([^\/]+)/)) {
          $this.val(newval2.pop());
      } else if (newval2 = $this.val().match(/(\embed\/)+([^\/]+)/)) {
          $this.val(newval2.pop().replace('?rel=0', ''));
      }
  }, 800);
});
```

In a pen : https://codepen.io/Laurentfrom47/pen/yLaLZLd

Comment: What is an example of an input that fails? What is an example of an input that passes?

Comment: You can see that in the pen

Comment: Your `$this` variables should be declared with `let` or `var`. As it is, both of your "paste" handlers are sharing the same global variable.

Comment: Also there's no need for a codepen. Stack Overflow has essentially the same facilities built in.

Comment: It's possible that the `maxlength` attribute you've got on your inputs is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.match()` has no problem.

The problem comes from the `maxlength="50"` attribute in your `<input>`. You are not getting only the first 11 characters of the video, but the first 50 characters of the URL... The rest gets truncated.